# Extract String Between Two Different Characters

Tags: sql

I am having some trouble trying to figure out a way to extract a string between two different characters. My issue here is that the column (*CONFIG_ID*) contains more that 75,000 rows and the format is not consistent, so I cannot figure out a way to get the numbers between E and B.

```
*CONFIG_ID*
6E15B1P
999E999B1P
1E3B1P
1E30B1P
5E24B1P
23E6B1P
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a CROSS APPLY to calculate the values only once.  Another nice thing about CROSS APPLY is that you can stack calculations and use them in the top SELECT

Notice the `nullif()` rather than throwing an error if the character is not found, it will return a NULL

**THIS ALSO ASSUMES there are no LEADING B's**

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([CONFIG_ID] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('6E15B1P')
,('999E999B1P')
,('1E3B1P')
,('1E30B1P')
,('5E24B1P')
,('23E6B1P')
,('23E6ZZZ') -- Notice No B

 
Select [CONFIG_ID]
      ,NewValue = substring([CONFIG_ID],P1,P2-P1)
 From @YourTable
 Cross Apply ( values (nullif(charindex('E',[CONFIG_ID]),0)+1
                      ,nullif(charindex('B',[CONFIG_ID]),0)
                      ) )B(P1,P2)
```

**Results**

```
CONFIG_ID   NewValue
6E15B1P     15
999E999B1P  999
1E3B1P      3
1E30B1P     30
5E24B1P     24
23E6B1P     6
23E6ZZZ     NULL  -- Notice No B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBSTRING(config_id,PATINDEX('%E%',config_id)+1,PATINDEX('%B%',config_id)-PATINDEX('%E%',config_id)-1)
```

As in:

```
WITH dat
AS
(
SELECT config_id
FROM (VALUES ('1E30B1P')) t(config_id)
) 
SELECT SUBSTRING(config_id,PATINDEX('%E%',config_id)+1,PATINDEX('%B%',config_id)-PATINDEX('%E%',config_id)-1)
FROM dat
```

Answer (score 0):

A cased substring of a left could be enough.

> ```
> select *
> , CASE 
>   WHEN [CONFIG_ID] LIKE '%E%B%'
>   THEN SUBSTRING(LEFT([CONFIG_ID], CHARINDEX('B',[CONFIG_ID],CHARINDEX('E',[CONFIG_ID]))),
>                  CHARINDEX('E',[CONFIG_ID]), LEN([CONFIG_ID]))
>   END AS [CONFIG_EB]
> from Your_Table
> ```

> | CONFIG_ID | CONFIG_EB |
> | --- | --- |
> | 6E15B1P | E15B |
> | 999E999B1P | E999B |
> | 1E3B1P | E3B |
> | 1E30B1P | E30B |
> | 5E24B1P | E24B |
> | 23E6B1P | E6B |
> | 23E678 | *null* |
> | 236789 | *null* |
> | 23B456 | *null* |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=97790b91147ec567fbad4f497db5fc0e)*